# Inserting Multiple Select statement in a Temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the query below:

```
Insert into #BidYTDRegions (Code,APAC,EMEA,NAMerica,LAMerica)
    select 'Payroll', Count(*) from DashboardData
    where DataType = 'Bid' and SMHQRegion = 'APAC'  
    and Services like '%Streamline Payroll%',
    Count(*) from DashboardData
    where DataType = 'Bid' and SMHQRegion = 'EMEA'  
    and Services like '%Streamline Payroll%',
    Count(*) from DashboardData
    where DataType = 'Bid' and SMHQRegion = 'N. America'    
    and Services like '%roll%'  ,
    Count(*) from DashboardData
    where DataType = 'Bid' and SMHQRegion = 'L. America'    
    and Services like '%roll%'
```

I am getting an error `Incorrect syntax near ','.`

All I am trying to do is insert some data into a temp table based on select statments. Below is my temp table

```
Create table #BidYTDRegions
(   
  Code nvarchar(50), 
  APAC int, 
  APACRatio nvarchar(20),
  EMEA int, 
  EMEARatio nvarchar(20),
  NAMerica int, 
  NAMericaRatio nvarchar(20),
  LAmerica int, 
  LAmericaRatio nvarchar(20),  
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want subqueries, which would be done like so:

```
Insert into #BidYTDRegions (Code,APAC,EMEA,NAMerica,LAMerica)
    select 'Payroll'
        ,(select Count(*) from DashboardData
          where DataType = 'Bid' and SMHQRegion = 'APAC'  
          and Services like '%Streamline Payroll%')
        ,(select Count(*) from DashboardData
          where DataType = 'Bid' and SMHQRegion = 'EMEA'  
          and Services like '%Streamline Payroll%')
        ,(select Count(*) from DashboardData
          where DataType = 'Bid' and SMHQRegion = 'N. America'    
          and Services like '%roll%')
        ,(select Count(*) from DashboardData
          where DataType = 'Bid' and SMHQRegion = 'L. America'    
          and Services like '%roll%')
```

Comment: That was it..Thank you so much for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
Insert into #BidYTDRegions (Code, APAC, EMEA, NAMerica, LAMerica)
    select 'Payroll',
            sum(case when SMHQRegion = 'APAC' and Services like '%Streamline Payroll%' then 1 else 0 end),
            sum(case when SMHQRegion = 'EMEA' and Services like '%Streamline Payroll%' then 1 else 0 end),
            sum(case when SMHQRegion = 'N. America' and Services like '%roll%' then 1 else 0 end),
            sum(case when SMHQRegion = 'S. America' and Services like '%roll%' then 1 else 0 end)
    from DashboardData
    where DataType = 'Bid';
```

It is unclear to me why the `Services` has a different comparison for different regions.  If it were the same, then that condition could be factored out and moved to the `WHERE` clause along with `DataType`.

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon..I have noticed you are mostly the first one to help out..Really appreciate it :)